# Iterator filter() double reference borrowing error

Tags: rust

I am trying to write some Rust code using some iterator magic, but I have a problem with double references and Rust's documentation:

```
#[derive(PartialEq,Eq)]
pub enum Token {
    ECOND,
    SCOND
}

pub fn validate(pgm: &Vec<Token>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    let valid1 = pgm.iter()
                    .filter(|&&item|
                        item == Token::SCOND || item == Token::ECOND
                    )
                    .fold(0, |acc: i64, ref x| -> i64 {
                        if x == &&Token::SCOND {
                            return acc + 1;
                        } else {
                            return acc - 1;
                        }
                    });

    if valid1 != 0 {
        return Err(());
    }
    return Ok(());
}
```

It gives me an error :

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
                        .filter(|&&item|
                              ^~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0507` to see a detailed explanation
note: attempting to move value to here
                        .filter(|&&item|
                               ^~~~
help: to prevent the move, use `ref item` or `ref mut item` to capture value by reference
```

As stated by [filter's doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), with double references I can write the code these ways, and it works:

```
.filter(|&item|
    *item == Token::SCOND || *item == Token::ECOND
)
```

And also like that:

```
.filter(|item|
    **item == Token::SCOND || **item == Token::ECOND
)
```

But how can I use my solution (which is also the doc solution)? I don't see where is my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between your `Token` and the doc's `i32` is that a `i32` is `Copy`.

Rust types are, by default, *affine types*: they may at most be used (transferred by value) once. `Copy` types are the exception to the rule, they can be used any number of times, because using them does not transfer ownership, it silently produces a `Clone` instead.

As a result, unless your `Token` type is made `Copy` (which also requires `Clone`), you cannot use the third form presented in the documentation of `filter`.

You can simply use:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Token { .... }
```

to make it `Copy`, or not use the third form. I would advise the latter unless you are comfortable guaranteeing to your clients that it will remain `Copy`.